# Where can I test my httpPost method?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

Could you please advice a Server against which I can test my Class which sends and receives a response to httpPost() method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heres a [free](http://www.snee.com/xml/crud/posttest.html) site:

```
http://www.snee.com/xml/crud/posttest.html
```

You can post to `http://www.snee.com/xml/crud/posttest.cgi`with two parameters put them as your key

`fname` and `lname` and will display the response.

Heres the entire source of the form

```
<html> 
<title>POST test</title> 
<body> 

<h1>posttest.html</h1> 

<form action="posttest.cgi" method="post"> 
<p>This form invokes an existing script called posttest.cgi:</p> 

<p>first name <input type="text" name="fname" size="40"/></p> 
<p>last name <input type="text" name="lname" size="40"/></p> 

<input type="submit" value="  go  " /> 

</form> 

</body></html>
```

Of coarse you can go to that site and check it out. Hope that helps

Heres a sample android code:

```
try{
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
"http://www.snee.com/xml/crud/posttest.cgi");

List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", "First name"));
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", "Last name"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
postParameters);

request.setEntity(formEntity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
.getContent()));

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
String line = "";
String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line + NL);
}
in.close();}catch(Exception ex){}
```

Comment: Don't you know why I can use this peace of code the only once (I've included it in onClickListener for my button) and then I have to turn off and turn on wifi connection? In logs I can see "12-27 21:39:50.136: WARN/GTalkService(21165):   -- caused by: java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out

Comment: it is in .cgi i want in php is there any option or cgi code ??